# Keras plot after model is finished explanaition

Tags: plot, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

It is not really a programming question, I apologise for that. I have trained my network and generated these graphs.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/89ibg.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH63e.jpg

I am struggling to find an answer to what do Accuracy vs Val_Accuracy and Loss vs Val_loss really represent. I do understand that if val_loss starts to jump high it means that there is over fitting going on and network just starts to memorise the data rather then learning. Could anyone explain in a bit more detail what they all mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During a neural network training - you usually provide two sets of data - a `train` one and `validation` one. Your training algorithm is taking data from a `train` set - and using a calculus and backpropagation it's trying to decrease a `cost` function which somehow represents how good your representation is (smaller the better). Aside of this - a `cost` is computed for a `validation` set which is not seen by a training algorithm - so one may check if model doesn't *overfit* on a `train` data provided (this happens if `train loss` is substancially smaller than `validation loss`). Despite `loss` different metrics might be computed - one of them might be e.g. `accuracy`. Sometimes they give you better insights into how your model works because `loss` might be hard to understand. Metrics give you better understanding on if your model works good.

Comment: Thank you very much